# Print all prime numbers that are less than n

Tags: java

I wrote the following code:

```
package primelessthanN;



public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int j;
        int n;
        n = 10;

        for (j = 3; j <=n; j++) {
            if (isPrime(j))
                System.out.println(j);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int m) {


        for (int i = 3; i <=m; i++) {
            if (m % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I do not know why it doesn't work and I am a little bit nervous.

Could any of you help me please and tell me where it is my mistake?

Comment: why are you nervous?  post your ouput and people will help

Comment: `m%m` is always 0. Change the loop to `i<m` or the `Math.sqrt(m)` you had before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. In `main` you iterate from 3 to sqrt(n), but you have to start from 2 (which is a prime) and iterate to n

   ```
   for (j = 2; j <=n; j++) {
      if (isPrime(j)) {
          System.out.println(j);
      }
   }
   ```
2. In `isPrime` you have to start the iteration from 2 since it is a prime number too.

   ```
   for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(m); i++) {
       if (m % i == 0)
           return false;
   }
   return true;
   ```

Comment: that's right, that was a mistake and I have changed it as you said. Still not printing me the prime numbers less than 10.

Comment: @RosuLaurentiu You should also iterate `i<m` and not `i<=m`.